Tanstack Table V8 - getRowModel() rows and flatRows empty on one site but not empty on another, what is happening?
I have the exact same built react app running on 2 sites hosted on the same server. The 2 sites are one for production and for test but to repeat right now they have the exact same built react app.
On Site 1 getRowModel() produces this:
{rows: Array(370), flatRows: Array(370), rowsById: {…}} - getCoreRowModel()
{rows: Array(36), flatRows: Array(776), rowsById: {…}} - getGroupedRowModel()
{rows: Array(0), flatRows: Array(0), rowsById: {…}} - getRowModel()

The rows and flatRows are empty in getRowModel()
On Site 2 getRowModel() produces this:
{rows: Array(370), flatRows: Array(370), rowsById: {…}} - getCoreRowModel()
{rows: Array(36), flatRows: Array(776), rowsById: {…}} - getGroupedRowModel()
{rows: Array(406), flatRows: Array(776), rowsById: {…}} - getRowModel()

The rows and flatRows are populated as expected.
I'm at a complete loss how this can be possible, any ideas?
I have various Tanstack Tables throughout my site they have never exhibited this behaviour, so I have them working everywhere except this one table
